# Порядок отрисовки объектов на игровой сцене

Tags: разработка-игр

Доброго времени суток.

Делаю 2D RPG видом сверху (как в обычных jrpg). Удалось реализовать систему столкновений и процедурную генерацию мира. И вот застрял на следующем - в каком порядке выводить объекты на экран чтобы они правильно перекрывали друг друга. 
К чему я пока пришел: имеется карта модели и карта отображения. Карта модели используется для расчета столкновений и при генерации мира - когда решается где и какой объект будет находиться. Вначале для хранения карты модели я использовал 2D массив. Но когда появились объекты в форме арки, а в ландшафте летающие острова стал хранить карту модели в 3D массиве чтобы было проще рассчитывать столкновения. Карта отображения - обыкновенная тайловая карта хранящееся в 2D массиве. 
Проблема возникла в следующем: на карте есть объекты площадь которых занимает несколько тайлов. Некоторые объекты могут нависать над другими - например деревья над крышами низких домов. Сперва я просто хотел отсортировать все объекты в зависимости от их координаты Z и Y. Но что если одна часть объекта высокая, а другая низкая, например: двух этажный дом с крыльцом. В этом случае, если рядом с домом генерируется дерево то необходимо учитывать рядом с какой его частью оно появилось и уже потом решать - сможет ли листва дерева находится над этой частью дома или нет. Резать изображения на части по высоте, а уже потом сортировать - ну во первых хотелось бы облегчить работы художнику, а во вторых я не знаю как из этих частей потом собрать целое изображение. 
В общем пришёл к следующему решению - программно нарезать изображение на маленькие квадраты, каждый из которых размером с тайл карты отображения, а в модели хранить 2D массив каждого конкретного изображения - где в каждой ячейке массива находится информация о высоте соответствующей части изображения. Сам 2D массив формируется на основе 3D маски объекта используемой для расчета столкновений. Способ хоть и рабочий, но уж какой-то замудренный и кажется мне очень кривым.
А какие способы вы бы посоветовали или можно ли как-то упростить мой подход?
P.s. интересует сам принцип, подход к решению задачи, а не реализация на том или ином движке.

Comment: "замудренный"? - почитайте про Z-буферирование 3D-движков, и Вы поймете, что дешево отделались.

Comment: Спасибо Igor. Вы натолкнули меня на мысль использовать подход Z - буфферирования чтобы избавиться от необходимости нарезать изображение даже в тех случаях, когда мы к примеру имеем дом в форме буквы "О" и в его центре находится высокий объект закрывающий собой задние стены этого дома, а передние стены закрывают собой часть этого объекта.